# Catel Orchestra theme only works in designer?

Tags: wpf, catel, fluent-ribbon, orchestra

Hello I'm trying to apply a theme to Fluent Ribbon but unfortunately it doesn't work. But what interesting in the visual studio designer everything works. Here is the code with I try to do it, and one more question. How to disable full screen mode in the main window?

`<Application x:Class="WLDA.Server.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Windows8/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>`

[image]

[Test App](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_irffxq3qZqR2Fodm5PZVZfVkk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by the Fluent Ribbon styles being automatically added by Orchestra for you (and they default to Office 2013).

One solution could be to remove the existing dictionary from `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` and add the Windows 8 instead.

You could use the Orchestra repository (with examples) to test if this works.